# Mostrar URL dependiendo de valor base de datos

Tags: php, sql

Tengo la siguiente tabla en mi base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que dependiendo de los valores de android, ios etc se muestre una url distinta.
Por ejemplo si android es 1 para este usuario, que se muestre la pagina web de android.

El código que he utilizado es el siguiente pero me estoy recibiendo 'undefined index' al hacer los get:

```
<?php

  $sql = "SELECT android, ios, macos, linux, windows FROM users";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

  $ios = $_GET["ios"];
  $android = $_GET["android"];

  if ($ios == 1) {
    header("Location: ../consejos/ios.html");
    die();
  } elseif ($android == 1) {
    header("Location: ../consejos/ios.html");
    die();
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Podrias editar tu pregunta para mostrar donde se envían los GET desde algun formulario.

Comment: ¿Y como haría eso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

creo que estas utilizando mal el GET .

Posiblemente tu solución sea

```
$s = "localhost";
$bd = "nombreBD";//nombre de tu base de datos
$u = "root"; //usuario
$p = ""; //contraseña

$conexion = new mysqli($s, $u, $p, $bd);
if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
    echo "no conectado";
}
$conexion->real_query("SELECT android, ios, macos, linux, windows FROM users"); 
$resultado = $conexion->use_result();
while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { 
  $ios = $fila["ios"];
  $android = $fila["android"];
}


    if ($ios == 1) {
    header("Location: ../consejos/ios.html");
    exit();
  } elseif ($android == 1) {
    header("Location: ../consejos/ios.html");
    exit();
  }
```

Comment: ¿Con el WHILE lo que hago no es pasar por todos los usuarios de la tabla? Yo solo quiero saber el del usuario activo. Con esto que me has dicho aunque lo cambie a iOS siempre me aparece android.

Comment: Podrias usar el id o el nombre en un WHERE en la consulta pero necesitas una forma de obtener esos valores, antes tienes un login ?

Comment: Si que lo tengo, podría utilizar $username=$_SESSION['username']; pero no sabría como implementarlo

Comment: El apartador de conexión lo tengo en otro php y lo incluyo al principio con un incluyo así <?php
require('../php/db.php');
include("../php/auth.php");

$username=$_SESSION['username'];
?>

Comment: En la logica de tu login pondrias AL PRINCIPIO session_start(); y supongo que obtienes la contraseña en alguna consulta, de igual forma guardarias el usuario y al validar la contraseña y que sea correcta guardarias en $_SESSION['username'] el usuario. Y en el archivo donde validas si es android o ios, igual pones session_start(); AL PRINCIPIO y obtienes tu $username = $_SESSION['username']; y lo usas en el WHERE

Comment: Funciona! Muchas gracias!